# Pass a value by reference in a function to find level of node in a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am trying to write a function to find the level of a node in a binary tree. Here is my implementation:

```
def level_of_node(root, node, level):
    if root is None:
        return -1

    if root.data == node:
        return level

    return level_of_node(root.left, node, level+1)
    return level_of_node(root.right, node, level+1)
```

Here is my tree:

```
root = Node(6)
root.left = Node(10)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(30)
root.left.right.left = Node(16)
root.left.right.right = Node(8)
root.right.right = Node(3)
root.right.left = Node(5)

level = 0
x = level_of_node(root, 16, level)
print x
```

When i call this function, it should return the level of node but it returns -1.

I think it is because level is passed by value. Can anyone suggest me better way to do it recursively ?

Comment: It's returning `None` because you don't `return` anything else in the vast majority of situations.

Comment: Hint:  What does your function return if `root != None` and `root.data != node`?

Comment: As well as the issues mentioned by the other two comments, you are not checking which of the children to visit in your code. In your current code, you will never visit root.right. Your binary tree structure in the second block of code also doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: Can you give me the correct implementation of this code, that would be helpful. @YXD